# How to place algorithm outside float?

Tags: floats, algorithms

Is there any elegent way to place algorithm without using `algorithm` environment?

Comment: I've added an answer which depends on what you're after in avoiding the `algorithm` environment. If it's not satisfactory, give some feedback and explain your use case.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *have* to put it in a float. But it depends on what you're after. If the intent is to avoid the `algorithm` float yet still have captions, then the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) provides `\captionof{<float type>}{<caption>}` that allows you to set a caption of a float *outside* a float. For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{algorithms,algorithmicx,caption}
\begin{document}

%\noindent
%\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm\label{euclid}}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
%\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

While [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) provides the floating `algorithm` environment, it's only used for the `algorithm` counter and float *type*. The above works for [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmic) and/or [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx).

It is advisable to contain the algorithm inside a box (like a `minipage`), but this may depend on the setting of the algorithm in the code itself. For example, `algorithmicx` sets its algorithms (in the `algorithmic` environment) as a list, which will break across the page boundary. If you don't want it, contain it.

---

[`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) provides its own "do not float" `[H]` float specifier, setting the contents in a `minipage` if used this way. So one would have to use

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
% <your algorithm here>
\end{algorithm}
```

under those conditions. A large amount of leg-work is done by the package at the start of the `algorithm` environment in order to set things up since it has its own interface (using `\;` to denote line-ends, otherwise known as a horizontal space in math-mode outside the environment).

Comment: The first code block raises `Package caption Warning: \setcaptiontype outside box or environment` now.

Comment: @user202729: True, since it is suggested to place the contents within a group (which is necessarily provided by a float/`minipage`). This is mentioned somewhat in the answer: "It is advisable to contain the algorithm inside a box (like a `minipage`)...", as well as in the commented code.